# XML entity references with unicode paths

Tags: java, xml, unicode

I'm caching XML entities so I don't have to fetch them from server, resulting in XML header tags like

```
<!ENTITY % xhtml-special-local SYSTEM "/Users/test/Library/Application Support/test/xhtml-special.ent" > %xhtml-special-local;
```

This works great unless the username contains öäå or similar non-ascii characters. With these, I get the following parser error

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /Users/test/Library/Application Support/testööö/xhtml-special.ent
```

How should the entity path be escaped to be accepted by the parser?

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by prepending file:/// to the path, like so

```
<!ENTITY % xhtml-special-local SYSTEM "file:////Users/test/Library/Application Support/test/xhtml-special.ent" > %xhtml-special-local;
```

Comment: Should be `///` rather than `////` but most systems are tolerant. The key thing is it should be a URI, not a filename.

Comment: And simply prepending "file://" is not the right way to turn a filename into a URI. You also need to deal with special characters. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a URI, not a filename. That means it should have "file://" at the start.

Secondly, URIs only allow ASCII characters. Some systems are more flexible and accept IRIs (an extension of URIs that permits non-ASCII characters), but there's nothing in the specs that endorses this. To be portable you need to use %XX escaping for non-ASCII characters. The easiest way to do this if you're in Java is with File.toURI().

```
    System.err.println(new File(
"/Users/test/Library/Application Support/testööö/xhtml-special.ent"
).toURI().toASCIIString());
```

outputs

```
file:/Users/test/Library/Application%20Support/test%C3%B6%C3%B6%C3%B6/xhtml-special.ent
```

The sequence %C3%B6 is the hex representation of the two octets making up the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character ö.